# 2 of 3 Domains resolve to same DocumentRoot on Apache 2.4.7 Virtual Host Configuration

Tags: apache, virtualhost, ubuntu-server

2 of 3 Domains resolve to same DocumentRoot. Single IP / multiple domain setup.

In the situation outlined here domain3.tld incorrectly resolves to same document root as domain2.tld

This is a cloud server hosted by 1and1.com where I have root access, Ubuntu 14.04 Apache 2.4.7 Server

During the virtual host configurations the following commands were employed: a2dissite a2ensite and service apache2 restart during activation and deactivation of virtual host .conf files located in /etc/apache2/sites-available

apache2ctl provided a full report on all loaded Virtual Hosts. The virtual hosts shown loaded are correct.

```
# /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S

VirtualHost configuration:
*:8443                 domain2.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/003-domain2.tld-le-ssl.conf:4)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 70.35.204.227 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-html.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 70.35.204.227 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-html.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost domain1.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-domain1.tld.conf:3)
                 alias www.domain1.tld
         port 80 namevhost domain2.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-domain2.tld.conf:3)
                 alias www.domain2.tld
         port 80 namevhost domain3.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/004-domain3.tld.conf:3)
                 alias www.domain3.tld
*:8080                 is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain1.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-domain1.tld.conf:50)
         port 8080 namevhost domain1.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-domain1.tld.conf:50)
                 alias www.domain1.tld
         port 8080 namevhost domain2.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-domain2.tld.conf:49)
                 alias www.domain2.tld
         port 8080 namevhost domain3.tld (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/004-domain3.tld.conf:44)
                 alias www.domain3.tld
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Relevant Directories

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available# ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1595 May 12 19:36 000-html.conf  <<< IP address of server
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2418 May 12 20:14 001-domain1.tld.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2517 May 12 20:14 002-domain2.tld.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1809 May 12 20:13 003-domain2.tld-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2383 May 12 20:12 004-domain3.tld.conf

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 May 12 03:52 000-html.conf -> ../sites-available/000-html.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 May 12 17:40 001-domain1.tld.conf -> ../sites-available/001-domain1.tld.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 May 12 17:55 002-domain2.tld.conf -> ../sites-available/002-domain2.tld.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 May 12 17:41 003-domain2.tld-le-ssl.conf -> ../sites-available/003-domain2.tld-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 May 12 18:10 004-domain3.tld.conf -> ../sites-available/004-domain3.tld.conf
```

Each virtual host configuration file contains the relevant

```
<VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080></VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8443></VirtualHost>  < For SSL, not using
```

I am listening on 3 ports in the /etc/apache2/ports.conf file

File /etc/apache2/sites-available/002-domain2.tld.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain2.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain2.tld
    #ServerAdmin Deprecated
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html-domain2.tld
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-port80-domain2.tld.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-port80-domain2.tld.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName domain2.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain2.tld
    #ServerAdmin Deprecated
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html-domain2.tld
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-port8080-domain2.tld.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-port8080-domain2.tld.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

File /etc/apache2/sites-available/004-domain3.tld.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain3.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain3.tld
    #ServerAdmin Deprecated
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html-domain3.tld
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-port80-domain3.tld.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-port80-domain3.tld.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName domain3.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain3.tld
    #ServerAdmin Deprecated
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html-domain3.tld
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-port8080-domain3.tld.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-port8080-domain3.tld.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea why my domain 3 is getting directed to the same document root as domain 2 ?  I see webhosts with 100s of virtual host all working perfectly, but not this simple setup I am working on.  Been at this for 3 days trying all variations of fixes I have found here and there in several forums.

Continued diagnostic discoveries: day 5
If the contents of the domain3 DocumentRoot are removed a blank page is served by Apache. When the contents of domain3 DocumentRoot are restored the contents of domain2 DocumentRoot are served once again.  This behavior is repeatable.

Comment: Need to see your original config. Not just what "apache2ctl -S" shows. Particularly what is in 004-domain3tld.conf

Comment: BazzDP: I added in the conf contents to the main question. Thanks

Comment: Can't spot anything obviously wrong with config (apart from fact two sites don't listen on 8443 - but I presume it's the port 80 or 8080 which is causing you issues?). Is it showing domain2 contents under domain3 URL or is it redirecting? Do you have any htaccess files in the DocumentRoot? What content is returned by your domains? Static HTML or dynamic content (e.g. PHP) - could it be a problem there rather than in Apache?